# SVG. What is the correct way to position an SVG tag in the DOM?

Tags: svg, d3.js

So, it is easy to set the width of an svg element (here using d3):

```
svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  300)
    .attr("height",  1024);
```

However, I need to have divs and svg elements positioned beside each other so I need to set an x,y position for the svg element. This does not work:

```
svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("x", 128)
.attr("y", 256)
.attr("width",  300)
.attr("height",  1024);
```

Setting a css class attribute that uses absolute positioning does work, but that is a bit of a pain. What is the correct solution here?

As I mentioned below in the comment I want to lay out N columns of svg/div pairs like so:

```
<svg>d3 coolness 0></svg><div>not so cool 0</div>
<svg>d3 coolness 1></svg><div>not so cool 1</div>
<svg>d3 coolness 2></svg><div>not so cool 2</div>
```

All in a single row.

I even tried stuffing positioning into the svg element like this:

```
$('svg').css({
    "left": 200 + "px",
    "top": 300 + "px"
});
```

No effect. Huh?

Comment: your final sentence has it right, why is that a pain? You could also stick them in a table or a flex box.

Comment: If you need the `<svg>` element to flow in the document, make sure it's `display` property is set to `inline` (most likely, it's set to `block` by default)

Comment: Here is a bit more context. I want a series of DOM elements layed out horizontally across the screen: <svg>stuff 0</svg> <div>stuff 1</div> <svg>stuff 2</svg> <div>stuff 3</div> .

Comment: You're trying to do inline/block-inline layout, but your elements use block display.

Comment: What Robert said, or use `float: left;`

Comment: Sigh. Fine, I'll use css. I just find the indirectness - and general chaos of - css to be a distraction. What ev.

Answer (score 0):

I have relented and will go ahead and use css as commenters have suggested.